# Using Iteration variable in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee, thymeleaf

Hi I am new to thymeleaf and am converting ma old project from jsp to thymeleaf.I am trying to convert a piece of code written in jsp which is :

```
<logic:iterate id="someForm" name="formName" property="nameList" indexId="i">
<%if (i%2==0)
{
 className="even";
 }
 else
 {
  className="odd";
 }
 %>
//some code here
```

can anyone help me with converting this code in thymeleaf ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're looking for is in the [Thymeleaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status).
Assuming you need to iterate over your collection to display `div` tags:

```
<div th:each="propName,iterStat : ${propNames}" th:class="${iterStat.odd}? 'odd' : 'even'">
    ...
</div
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case your div already has a class and you want to append a new class, use th:classappend:

```
<div class="col-md-12" th:each="propName,iterStat : ${propNames}" th:classappend="${iterStat.odd}? 'odd' : 'even'">
...
```